# Full-text search does not find some prefixes

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014's full-text search capabilites to find documents in a database that start with a given prefix. Some queries, however, do not yield any results, while they should.

Take the following example:

```
SELECT * FROM [Profile].[DocumentView] WHERE CONTAINS(Content, '"Friedenseins*"')

(24 row(s) affected)

SELECT * FROM [Profile].[DocumentView] WHERE CONTAINS(Content, '"Friedensein*"')

(0 row(s) affected)

SELECT * FROM [Profile].[DocumentView] WHERE CONTAINS(Content, '"Friedensei*"')

(29 row(s) affected)
```

I understand the first and third result, but not the second one. The stoplist for the full-text index is switched off. The language for the wordbreaker is set to German.

EDIT:
The suggestion to use `FREETEXT` instead is not a solution for this particular case, as I need `CONTAINS`'s proximity search feature.

Comment: Means you don't have "word" in Content column with the following ("Friedensein"), but you have "words" in the column with the following startings("Friedenseins","Friedensei").

Comment: The target word is actually "Friedenseinsätze", which is found by the fist and the third query, but not by the second.

Comment: Never come across this kind of situation, eager to hear from experts. +1

Comment: I have put a [sample DDL and reproduction of the problem on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/954da/1)

Comment: I created an issue on Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1032815

Comment: Strange indeed. Change that first letter from F to G and suddenly it works. I played with the sqlfiddle and found the same problem using English instead of German. I've worked pretty extensively with SQL Server full text and never seen anything like this!

Comment: See the link to connect for an anwser by Microsoft.

Comment: Please consider posting a self answer as you have an explanation now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the word-breakers, which do not include the phrase id, so the second query gets translated into the equivalent of (pseudo-SQL)

```
SELECT * FROM [Profile].[DocumentView] WHERE Content LIKE
    ((friedensein* OR frieden*) in Position 1) AND (sein* in Position 2)
```

But "Friedenseinsätze" has "einsätze" in Position 2. With the proper phrase id, the query would become

```
SELECT * FROM [Profile].[DocumentView] WHERE Content LIKE
    ((friedensein* in Position 1) OR ((frieden* in Position 1) AND (sein* in Position 2)))
```

The Office team has been informed. The [Connect Thread](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1032815) will be updated when new information is available.

**UPDATE:** The issue was resolved as *Won't Fix*.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for posting this question Mathias.  I just wanted to point out the suggestion from Microsoft (via https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1032815) was to switch to the format

```
 SELECT * FROM [Profile].[DocumentView] WHERE FREETEXT(Content, '"Friedensein*"')
```

While this doesn't help Mathias, it was able to help me out and might help the reader.

In my case, I had a problem with searching a date string stored in a text field (nvarchar).  My simple example was that this DIDN'T WORK:

```
select * from Sample
where CONTAINS(*, '"1/5/2015*"')
```

... returns nothing. However, when I switch to FREETEXT as follows, it does return as expected.

```
select * from Sample
where FREETEXT(*, '"1/5/2015*"')
```

I am also using SQL 2014.  Please vote up the MS Connect link if you are also having this problem.

**UPDATE 1/8/2015:**

I have since discovered that this solution does not work in my case since FREETEXT brings back other date values that are "similar" or so it seems. With my example of 1/5/2015 above, I'm also getting back hits on 1/2/2015, 1/6/2015 and so on.  In fact, if I query against 12/5/2014 (former year) I get hits all across the year, so the "similar" seems to be defined by the year in this case.

For reference, here is the SQL documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx